# Adding Primefaces Extensions to Netbeans Ant Project

Tags: netbeans, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have an ant project developed with Netbeans. I want to add primefaces extensions to that. I downloaded the jar file and added it as an extension, but there is an error of dependencies. Is there any way to add primefaces extensions without using maven ?

```
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jar:file:/D:/SC/ruhunu/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-extensions-1.0.0.RC1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.extensions.component.masterdetail.MasterDetailRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/component/menuitem/UIMenuItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `common-lang3.3.1.jar` and add it to the project library